# Exclude addresses from checkout

Tags: shipping-address, customer-address

Please Help me on this,
We have a one customer which has three different addresses in his account.in to the entity of address i have a select attribute field with values A,B and C.

My question is how can i exclude those addresses in checkout which have the C value in that specific address attribute?

i am new so i can not found the exact way for that, please help me.
many thanks